# ElasticSearch Match Query fuzzines on numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

If I search for tokens with numbers the fuzzines does not work right.

```
Dokument:
"Nice Photo S61"
```

Gives me a result on the query

"Nices"

But not as soon I would use

"S6"

I dont get a Result

Here is my query

```
GET /index1/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
         "url1" : {
             "query" : "s6",
             "fuzziness": "auto",
             "prefix_length": "3",
              "max_expansions": 6,
              "operator":  "and"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are my Index Settings:

```
  PUT /index1/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "product_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",

          "tokenizer": "punctuation", 
          "filter": [
            "lowercase" 
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "punctuation": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "[-_.:~ ]"
        }
      }
      }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "index1" : {
      "properties" : {
        "url":{
        "type" :"text",
        "analyzer" : "product_analyzer"
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not about numbers. 
When setting `fuzziness` to `auto` means to auto generate the edit distance base on your term.

> AUTO
>
> Generates an edit distance based on the length of the term. Low and
>   high distance arguments may be optionally provided AUTO:[low],[high].
>   If not specified, the default values are 3 and 6, equivalent to
>   AUTO:3,6 that make for lengths:
>
> 0..2 Must match exactly
>
> 3..5 One edit allowed
>
> >5 Two edits allowed AUTO should generally be the preferred value for fuzziness.

And

> prefix_length
>
> The number of initial characters which will not be “fuzzified”. This helps to reduce the number of terms which must be examined. Defaults to 0.

So you can change your query to this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
         "url1" : {
             "query" : "S6",
             "fuzziness": "1",
             "prefix_length": "0",
              "max_expansions": 6,
              "operator":  "and"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

refs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Comment: I still get no results on s6 or 61 my tokenizer is "tokenizer": {
        "punctuation": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "[-_.:~ ]"

Comment: @MichaelMüller would you like to append your index settings and mapping to your question?

Comment: Sure, just did so

Comment: Still can't reproduce your problem

Comment: @a.i., just noticed your answer.. going to upvote yours

Comment: It works now. I just shut down yesterday and today bottet again and paste the same string. Which proves computers are also just humans. thank alot!

Comment: I'm glad it helps. Feel free to accept this answer to help others suffer the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few considerations.

- In your posted examples, your query is trying to match the field `url1`, but in your mapping you defined the field `url`. I'll assume it was just a typo in your examples.
- In your query, you're setting a prefix length of 3 characters, but then you search for `s6`, which obviously doesn't match the length condition.
- In your query, you set the `fuzziness` value to `AUTO`, which for strings <= 2 characters means that your term must match exactly (see [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/common-options.html#fuzziness))